# Delete nodes after certain time xcode sprite kit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have made a simple game where many sprite nodes are being shoot out of an other ball. My problem is that the nodes are being collected at the end of the screen. So... I want the nodes to disappear after a certain time so the game won't be slow.

This is the necessary code for the problem i think.
Would love som help, thanks!

```
var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: "BallMovement", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

func BallMovement(){


    Ball2 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Ball")
    Ball2.setScale(0.5)
    Ball2.position = CGPointMake(Ball.position.x, Ball.position.y)
    Ball2.name = "Ball2"


    Ball2.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: Ball2.size)
    Ball2.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    Ball2.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
    Ball2.physicsBody?.friction = 0.4
    Ball2.physicsBody?.restitution = 0.1

    Ball2.zPosition = 1
    addChild(Ball2)

    let action = SKAction.moveToX(self.size.width, duration: 4)
    Ball2.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(action))


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try somthing like that:

```
Ball2.runAction(SKAction.sequence([SKAction.repeatAction(action, count: 1000),SKAction.removeFromParent()];
```

Your `action` will repeated 1000 times and the the associated node will be removed from the parent node.

Comment: Instead of doing it 1000 times,  just do waitForDuration and the time limit you want to wait